# Qt: How to update QStringList when QListView gets new entries

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qstringlistmodel, qstringlist

I have a `QListView _listView` whose model is `QStringListModel _model`, whose `QStringList` is `_locations`. Here's the code:

```
_locations << "Sarajevo" << "Tesanj" << "Graz";

_model = new QStringListModel(this);
_model->setStringList(_locations);

_listView = new QListView(this);
_listView->setModel(_model);
_listView->setEditTriggers(
      QAbstractItemView::EditTrigger::DoubleClicked |
      QAbstractItemView::EditTrigger::AnyKeyPressed);
```

and the slots that edit the `_listView`:

```
void Dialog_EditLocations::onKey_del()
{
    QModelIndex _index;
    _index = _listView->currentIndex();
    _model->removeRow(_index.row());
}

void Dialog_EditLocations::onClick_add()
{
    if (_edAddLocation->text() == "") return;
    int row = _model->rowCount();
    _model->insertRow(row);
    QModelIndex _index;
    _index = _model->index(row);
    _model->setData(_index, _edAddLocation->text());
    _edAddLocation->clear();    
}
```

After editing the list in list view widget, I want to store it in a file. When I store the _locations it saves the original list from the first row of the code, even though I added new items.

How to make the code update the `_locations` whenever I make a new entry in the `_listView`, or at least how to fetch the list that is visible in the `_listView`?

Comment: To avoid duplication and confusion, instead of `_locations` make `_model` a class attribute. Then access the string list from `_model`.

Comment: That's right, _locations is totally unnecessary. It serves only to initialize the private list of the _model. I incorrectly thought that the _locations would be constantly referred to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QStringListModel::stringList()`, it returns all current items from model that is what you see in *listview* widget, including any modifications (adding,removing rows).

At the end of `onClick_add` slot you can add:

```
_locations = _model->stringList();
```